# Input Data rate in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I am reading text data from a file and processing it to produce results using apache storm. I want to experiment with different input data rates.  I want to know, how will I change the input data rate in apache storm in this setting. Also is the input data rate is:

Number of tuples emitted by spout/Time

Answer (score 0):

By default, Storm will pull tuples out of the spout as fast as possible. You can interact with this via a few settings:

`topology.max.spout.pending` defines how many tuples can be emitted into the topology before Storm will throttle the spout and wait for some of the tuples to be acked. By default this is uncapped.

`topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms` defines how many milliseconds Storm will pause between calls to `nextTuple` on the spout, if a call to `nextTuple` produces no output. This is 1ms by default.

Comment: Ok so by changing topology.max.spout.pending value, suppose its 100 so is the input data rate will be 100 tuples/sec or if 50000 then the rate will be 50000 tuples/sec?

Comment: No. Setting max.spout.pending to 100 will just mean that there will only be 100 unacked tuples in-flight at a time in the topology. The settings I mentioned help you do flow control to avoid overwhelming your bolts. If you need a specific data rate, you will probably need to manually build this functionality into the spout.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the suggestions